# How to listen on `meta m` event and stop browser goes to minimize?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a website on chrome in Mac. The `meta+m` hotkey will minimize the browser. Is there a way for me to listen on this key event and stop it from going to minimize?

I tried below code it works but I am looking for a better solution:

```
$('#myinput').on('keydown', e => {

        if (e.key === 'Meta') {
            metaPressed = true;
        }
        if (e.key === 'm' && metaPressed) {
            console.log('klsjdflkasj')
            e.preventDefault();
        }
}
$('#myinput').on('keyup', e => {

        if (e.key === 'Meta') {
            metaPressed = false;
        }
}
```

basically, it works by remembering the `meta` keypress and check the next input character. The above code works fine but is there any solution works as below:

```
mydom.on('meta m', () => { ... })
```

Comment: Better how? Please include some objective criteria by which answers will be judged. Hopefully not code length -- I mean, you could get 50 answers each a few bytes shorter than the last via various minifying strategies.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for your advice. I have revised my question.